# Java Web Start внутри браузера

Tags: javaws, applet, java

Продолжаю разбираться с Java апплетами и вот что нашел на странице, посвященной Java Web Start на [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B4.D1.83_Java_Web_Start_.D0.B8_.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.BB.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8).

> Приложения, созданные с помощью
> технологии Java Web Start, не
> запускаются внутри браузера. Они
> отображаются вне браузера.
>
> Приложения, созданные с помощью
> технологии Java Web Start, можно
> запустить с помощью  браузера, однако
> механизм, лежащий в основе этого
> процесса, совершенно отличен от
> запуска аплетов.

Как запустить Web Start (по сути обычное desktop приложение с функцией main) приложение внутри браузера?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем ясен.. вы хотите запустить его так, чтобы оно работало внутри браузера или чтобы оно работало отдельно, но запускалось из браузера?

Comment: Чтоб приложение работало в браузере, как апплет или флэш.

Comment: Почему это так необходимо? Почему нельзя просто запустить внешнее приложение?

Comment: Пользователи могут испугаться или не поймут что происходит. Желательно приложение представить в виде, привычном всем, как флэш, например.
Просто если есть возможность обычное Java приложение с функцией main встроить на страницу браузера и использовать как настольное приложение, то зачем делать апплет?

Comment: Такой возможности нет. К тому же, я не понимаю, чем апплет не устраивает? Вы ведь сами сказали, что надо чтобы было как флеш. Так вот апплет и будет как флеш. Ничто не мешает сделать этот апплет таким же, как обычное приложение, только без своего окна, а внутри браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложения, созданные с помощью технологии Java Web Start  - некорректная формулировка вообще. Приложения не создают по этой технологии. Java Web Start - это технология деплоймента приложений, а не их разработки.

Если вы хотите запустить обычное desktop приложение, то используйте Java Web Start. Оформите правильно JNLP. На веб-странице делаете ссылку на этот JNLP-файл. При этом приложение стартует не **в** браузере, а **из** него.

В самом браузере работает **только апплет**. В то же время, ничто не мешает апплету открыть новое внешнее окно.

Comment: "Приложения, созданные с помощью технологии Java Web Start" - это цитата с Википедии, я вставил как есть. Очевидно, что статья переводная и в данном случае выбран неудачный вариант перевода.

Comment: Я вот тоже категорически против вылезающих из страницы окон. Это кошмарное зло. В википедии же пишут (автор процитировал), что можно прямо в на странице как-то запустить десктопное приложение. Вот об этом и вопрос.

Comment: Я нигде не вижу ни в цитате, ни в полной статье такого утверждения..

Comment: Да-да, я понял что у меня с Википедией возникло недопонимание.

Comment: Блин, и правда ведь :(